# How to change user of SD card from Root

Tags: permissions, sd-card

I just recently got a Chromebook and now have Linux installed on it, and I am trying to get steam games onto my sd card. I initially had the issue in that it would not install anything on a drive with no execute permissions, so I reformatted the SD card into ext4 with Gparted. The issue I have now is that I cannot change permissions, and it has the user listed as root. I have tried multiple 'fixes' that I have found online, but none have been of any help so far. I tried just changing the permissions `sudo chown yourusername /media/disk/` but of course, that did nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue. I accidentally formatted my SD card into ext4 with GParted. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

can you provide the ouptup of that command :

(if your SD card is mounted there /media/disk)

> ls -la /media/disk

Otherwise you can try to mount it from another user

> mount -t deviceFileFormat -o
>   umask=filePermissons,gid=ownerGroupID,uid=ownerID /device /mountpoint